# Display a route without DirectionsRenderer in Google Map V3

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to draw my own route without a `DirectionsRenderer`.

Here is my code:

```
var map;
var directionsService;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = { mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
      origin: 'שדי חמד',
      destination: 'כפר סבא',
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      map.fitBounds(directionResult.routes[0].bounds);
      createPolyline(response);
    }
  });
}

function createPolyline(directionResult) {
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
      path: directionResult.routes[0].overview_path,
      strokeColor: '#FF0000',
      strokeOpacity: 0.5,
      strokeWeight: 4
  });

  line.setMap(map);

  for (var i = 0; i < line.getPath().length; i++) {
      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          icon: { path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE, scale: 3 },  
          position: line.getPath().getAt(i),
          map: map
      });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

All I get is a gray window, not even a map.
When sending the `DirectionsService's` response to the `DirectionsRenderer` I get both polylines.

Any advice will be welcome.

Comment: [example of custom directions renderer](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_directions_custom_iconsC.html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I get a javascript error "directionResult is undefined"

on this line:

```
  map.fitBounds(directionResult.routes[0].bounds);
```

If I fix that (change it to response) it works.

[working example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_simpleMap_directions.html)

BTW - I would not suggest using overview_path; if the path is long or complex, that doesn't have enough detail in it.

**code snippet:**

```js
var map;
var directionsService;

function initialize() {
  var mapOptions = {
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

  directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
  calcRoute();
}

function calcRoute() {
  var request = {
    origin: 'שדי חמד',
    destination: 'כפר סבא',
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.WALKING
  };

  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      map.fitBounds(response.routes[0].bounds);
      createPolyline(response);
    }
  });
}

function createPolyline(directionResult) {
  var line = new google.maps.Polyline({
    path: directionResult.routes[0].overview_path,
    strokeColor: '#FF0000',
    strokeOpacity: 0.5,
    strokeWeight: 4
  });

  line.setMap(map);

  for (var i = 0; i < line.getPath().length; i++) {
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
      icon: {
        path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
        scale: 3
      },
      position: line.getPath().getAt(i),
      map: map
    });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html,
body,
#map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```